# Handling exceptions assert to NumPy testing in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, exception, assert

Understanding someone code and met this:

There is a function:

```
 def some_func():
       print("Hello")
       assert(len(y)==len(p))
       print("First assert")
       assert(p.all()<=0.99999)
       print("Second assert")
       return 1
```

Next, call assert_raises:

```
np.testing.assert_raises(AssertionError, some_func, np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

In the output, we simply get Hello without exception messages:

```
Hello
```

Next, call the function assert_array_less:

```
np.testing.assert_array_less(some_func(np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3])), np.inf)
```

In the output, we get Hello First assert and then an error message and an AssertionError exception:

```
Hello
First assert
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-df1a32b4f5a0> in <module>()
      9 np.testing.assert_raises(AssertionError, some_func, np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
     10 
---> 11 np.testing.assert_array_less(some_func(np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3])), np.inf)

<ipython-input-26-df1a32b4f5a0> in some_func(a, b)
      3     assert(len(a)==len(b))
      4     print("First assert")
----> 5     assert(a.all()<=0.99999)
      6     print("Second assert")
      7     return 1

AssertionError:
```

**Question:**

**Why in 1 case the code just stops and no exceptions are thrown, although it is called first assert in some_func ()?**

**And why in the second does not happen the same as in the first, and an exception is thrown?**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you show, I'm going to guess that the actual definition of your `some_func` function is:

```
def some_func(a, b):
    print("Hello")
    assert(len(a)==len(b))
    print("First assert")
    assert(a.all()<=0.99999)
    print("Second assert")
    return 1
```

Given that, here's the exact rundown on what happened during your `assert` calls:

- You call

  ```
  np.testing.assert_raises(AssertionError, some_func, np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
  ```

  - The `np.testing.assert_raises` function in turn calls

    ```
    some_func(np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
    ```

    - The first line of `some_func` runs, and prints `Hello`.
    - Next, `some_func` tries to assert that the lengths of `a` and `b` are the same. However, the length of `a` is 3 and the length of `b` is 5, so the assertion fails. This causes an `AssertionError` to be thrown. At this point, execution of `some_func` is terminated, and control returns to `assert_raises`.
  - `assert_raises` was told to expect an `AssertionError` via the first argument passed to it. It sees that an `AssertionError` has indeed been thrown, so from its perspective all is well. It handles the `AssertionError` (preventing it from creating an error message that would be shown to you, the user), and execution of `assert_raises` ends normally.
- Next you call

  ```
  np.testing.assert_array_less(some_func(np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([1, 2, 3])), np.inf)
  ```

  - Once again, the first line of `some_func` runs and prints `Hello`.
  - This time, `len(a)==len(b)==3`, so the `assert` passes and execution of `some_func` continues normally.
  - Next the third line of `some_func` runs and prints `First assert`.
  - Every value in `a` is nonzero, so `a.all()` is `True`. The boolean value `True` has a numeric value of `1`. Thus, `a.all()<=0.99999` is `False` and so the `assert` fails. At this point, an `AssertionError` is raised and the execution of `some_func` is terminated.
- This time, `some_func` was running in the top-level scope (if it had successfully completed, `np.testing.assert_array_less` would have been called and the return value of `some_func` would have been passed to it). Unlike the last time `some_func` was called there is no enclosing function that will handle the `AssertionError` that was raised. This means that the `AssertionError` will propagate and produce the visible error message that gets printed out beneath `First assert`.

And that's the whole story.